# overflow scroll in cordova (css) on android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, overscroll

I have the following class as a scrollable area in a div:

```
.content-wrap {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
position:absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
width: 100%;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-o-backface-visibility: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

When I run my app in ios i can scroll above 0 (eg. negative scroll value). But on android I can scroll above 0px. I dont want my entire "view" to be overscroll so I set this pref:

How can I make a div in a div accept overscroll using css?

Thanks

Comment: IOS vs Android scroll not same. You can use iScroll for android

Comment: ok, not possible with css?

Comment: Did you found a solution?